# Is there a way to write the actions "car" and "cdr" from scheme into Java?

Tags: java, scheme

Basically what is needed is the ability to use Lisp expression like car (returns a pointer to the first part of a multi-list) and cdr (returns a pointer to the second part of a multi-list). Pretty much the "car" and "cdr" need to be pointing to the first and second positions of a list.

Comment: @John3136 - Not just you. DaMan96 - How about some more explanation about what you want to do. Maybe also show some code that demonstrates what you're looking to do. Help us help you.

Comment: @theB so basically what is needed is the ability to use Lisp expression like car (returns a pointer to the first part of a multi-list) and cdr (returns a pointer to the second part of a multi-list). Pretty much the "car" and "cdr" need to be pointing to the first and second positions of a list.

Comment: You should [edit] that into your question.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    static <T> T car(List<T> list) {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    static <T> List<T> cdr(List<T> list) {
        return list.subList(1,list.size());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D");

        String head = car(list);
        List<String> tail = cdr(list);

        System.out.println(head); // "A"
        System.out.println(String.join(",", tail)); // "B,C,D"
    }
}
```